# Ldap error code 32

Tags: active-directory, ldap, synchronization, openldap

I'm trying to synchronize OpenLDAP and Active directory together. To do so I'm using a program called LSC-Project which is specified to do this sort of thing.

I have configured the program the best I can however I can't find a way to shake off the following error:

```
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: [LDAP: error code 32 - 0000208D: NameErr: DSID-
031001CD,
problem 2001 (NO_OBJECT), data 0, best match of:
'DC=domname,DC=com'
]; remaining name 
'uid=user1,ou=Users'

May 09 15:19:25 - ERROR - Error while synchronizing ID uid=user1,ou=Users:
java.lang.Exception:
Technical problem while applying modifications to directory
dn: uid=user1,ou=Users,dc=domname,dc=com
changetype: add
userPassword: 3+kU2th/WMo/v553A24a3SBw2kU=
objectClass: uid
```

This is the configuration file that the program runs on:

```
############################### 
Destination LDAP directory #
##############################

dst.java.naming.provider.url = ldap://192.168.1.3:389/dc=Windows,dc=com  
dst.java.naming.security.authentication = simple
dst.java.naming.security.principal = cn=Administrator,cn=Users,dc=Windows,dc=com
dst.java.naming.security.credentials = 11111
dst.java.naming.referral = ignore
dst.java.naming.ldap.derefAliases = never
dst.java.naming.factory.initial = com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory
dst.java.naming.ldap.version = 3
dst.java.naming.ldap.pageSize = 1000

#########################
Source LDAP directory 
#########################

src.java.naming.provider.url = ldap://192.168.1.2:389/dc=Linux,dc=com
src.java.naming.security.authentication = simple
src.java.naming.security.principal = uid=root,ou=users,dc=Linux,dc=com
src.java.naming.security.credentials = 11111
src.java.naming.referral = ignore
src.java.naming.ldap.derefAliases = never
src.java.naming.factory.initial = com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory
src.java.naming.ldap.version = 3

#######################
Tasks configuration 
#######################

lsc.tasks = Administrator
lsc.tasks.Administrator.srcService = org.lsc.jndi.SimpleJndiSrcService
lsc.tasks.Administrator.srcService.baseDn = ou=users
lsc.tasks.Administrator.srcService.filterAll = (&(objectClass=person))
lsc.tasks.Administrator.srcService.pivotAttrs = uid 
lsc.tasks.Administrator.srcService.filterId = (&(objectClass=person)(uid={uid}))
lsc.tasks.Administrator.srcService.attrs = description uid userPassword

lsc.tasks.Administrator.dstService = org.lsc.jndi.SimpleJndiDstService
lsc.tasks.Administrator.dstService.baseDn = cn=Users
lsc.tasks.Administrator.dstService.filterAll = (&(cn=*)(objectClass=organizationalPerson))
lsc.tasks.Administrator.dstService.pivotAttrs = cn, top, person, user, organizationalPerson
lsc.tasks.Administrator.dstService.filterId = (&(objectClass=user) (sAMAccountName={cn}))
lsc.tasks.Administrator.dstService.attrs = description cn userPassword objectClass

lsc.tasks.Administrator.bean = org.lsc.beans.SimpleBean
lsc.tasks.Administrator.dn = "uid=" + srcBean.getAttributeValueById("uid") + ",ou=Users"

dn.real_root = dc=Domname,dc=com

############################# 
Syncoptions configuration 
#############################

lsc.syncoptions.Administrator = org.lsc.beans.syncoptions.PropertiesBasedSyncOptions
lsc.syncoptions.Administrator.default.action = M
lsc.syncoptions.Administrator.objectClass.action = M
lsc.syncoptions.Administrator.objectClass.force_value = srcBean.getAttributeValueById("cn").toUpperCase()
lsc.syncoptions.Administrator.userPassword.default_value = SecurityUtils.hash(SecurityUtils.HASH_SHA1, "defaultPassword")
lsc.syncoptions.Administrator.default.delimiter=;
lsc.syncoptions.Administrator.objectClass.force_value = "top";"user";"person";"organizationalPerson"
lsc.syncoptions.Administrator.userPrincipalName.force_value = srcBean.getAttributeValueById("uid") + "@Domname.com"
lsc.syncoptions.Administrator.userAccountControl.create_value = AD.userAccountControlSet ( "0", [AD.UAC_SET_NORMAL_ACCOUNT])
```

I'm suspecting that it has something to do with the baseDn of the Task configuration in the part of the source configuration.

The OSs is ubuntu 10.04 and Windows2K3

Someone suggested to me to make a manual sync between them but I have not found any guides to do so. And this program is pretty much the only thing that says that is does this kind of job without costs.

Answer (score 10):

The `baseDn` should be the distinguished name of the base object of the search, for example, `ou=users,dc=domname,dc=com`.

#### see also

- [LDAP: Mastering Search Filters](http://ff1959.wordpress.com/2011/09/21/mastering-ldap-search-filters/)
- [LDAP: Search best practices](http://www.ldapguru.info/ldap/ldap-search-best-practices.html)
- [LDAP: Programming practices](http://ff1959.wordpress.com/2011/10/27/ldap-programming-best-practices/)

Comment: I did so and it gave a sightly different error:
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: [LDAP: error code 32 - No such Object]; remaining name 'ou=users,dc=domname,dc=com'

Empty or non existant source

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I am running into the same issue. Please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: @Terry Gardner LDAP: Search best practices link is broken. Please update it.

Comment: I've resolved my similar issue by making users a cn lookup and groups an ou lookup.  Also, groups MUST be in a separate container from users.  Any other combination results in the error listed (yet, actually functions fine, just throws a bunch of errors in the log).

Answer (score 10):

The main reason for `NameNotFoundException` is that the object which you're searching **doesn't exist** or the **container** in which you are searching is **not correct**.

Comment: No idea about this downvote. It is an correct answer so far.

Comment: Probably because it does not give a hint how to fix it.

Answer (score 4):

In case of Spring-ldap, we used to get this error when we specify the baseDn in the context file(LdapContextSource bean) and also in createUser code to build userDn.we need not specify the dc again in the `buildUserDn()`

```
protected Name buildUserDn(String userName) {
   DistinguishedName dn = new DistinguishedName();

   //only cn is required as the base dn is already specified in context file

   dn.add("cn", userName); 

   return dn;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In Active Directory: `Users` catalog is `container` class, not OrganizationalUnit, so you should use: `cn=users,dc=domname,dc=com`