# Spring LDAP Name not found Exception

Tags: java, spring, ldap

How to fetch the user details from LDAP ?

I am using the below LDAP details for getting the user details but I am unable to fetch the user details could any one help

```
    LDAP Details :        
    URL: ldap://xxxx.com:389
    base: "ou-xxx,dc=xxx,dc=xxx"
    username: "cn=xx,ou=xxx,dc=xxx,dc=xxx"
    password:"xxxx"
```

I am maintaining these details from `application.yml` file and I am fetching these details in the service class could some one please help in looking the above configurations am I doing mistake. Thanks for any help

```
"error :error code- 32-0000208D,proble 20Name not found exception"
```

Comment: Can you share the LDAP query you send? Maybe the lines of code where the Exception is thrown?

Comment: related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10607865/ldap-error-code-32

Comment: Your base looks wrong. I suspect it should read `ou=xxx,dc=xxx,dc=xxx` instead of `ou-xxx,dc=xxx,dc=xxx`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the base from your settings you will certainly get this error code:

> ou-xxx,dc=xxx,dc=xxx

is not a valid distinguished name and will cannot be found.

It should certainly read:

> ou=xxx,dc=xxx,dc=xxx